# Why does a blocking thread consume more then async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

See this question and answer;

[Why use async controllers, when IIS already handles the request concurrency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239722/why-use-async-controllers-when-iis-already-handles-the-request-concurrency)

Ok, a thread consumes more resources then the async/await construction, but *why*? What is the core difference? You still need to remember all state etc, don't you?

Why would a thread pool be limited, but can you have tons of more idle async/await constructions?

Is it because async/await knows more about your application?

Comment: Async/await is slower than a propper multi-threaded server... Especially if you bring out completion ports...

Comment: Async/awit is basically just a fancy alternative for the Begin... End... Pattern

Comment: @AK_ Can you provide any evidence to support this conclusion?

Comment: Not anything I can share here... But async/await for IO internally uses completion ports,  and wraps your code in tasks. You could write a faster implementation yourself avoiding Tasks and their overhead... Of course it would not be fun...

Comment: @ak_ what "task overhead" specifically are you referring to? There shouldn't be anything but the negligible indirections from competing the taskcompletionsource.

Comment: @JesseCarter all built-in async method in .Net internally call `BeginXXX`/`EndXXX`. But that's not the point. It allows you to use the compiler magic of async-await.

Comment: @i3arnon I'm aware of Begin/End, I was referring to the statement he made that a proper multi-threaded server is faster than one leveraging asynchrony

Comment: @Voo what you call 'negligible' could mean many hundreads of requests per second... I agree it's almost always worth it... But still...

Comment: @ak_ If you actually made benchmarks to test this, you should post the code on code review, because if you really saw a noticeable (10% higher throughput?) with your hand rolled solution I'd more likely assume some flaw in the benchmark (no work in the actual request handle seems an obvious candidate, but there's other more technical problems I can think of). But it'd certainly be interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's imagine a web-server. Most of his time, all he does is wait. it doesn't really CPU-bound usually, but more of I/O bound. It waits for network I/O, disk I/O etc. After every time he waits, he has something (usually very short to do) and then all he does is waiting again. Now, the interesting part is what happend **while he waits**. In the most "trivial" case (that of course is absolutely not production), you would create a thread to deal with every socket you have.

Now, each of those threads has it's own cost. Some handles, 1MB of stack space... And of course, not all those threads can run in the same time - so the OS scheduler need to deal with that and choose the right thread to run each time (which means A LOT of context switching). It will work for 1 clients. It'll work for 10 clients. But, let's imagine 10,000 clients at the same time. 10,000 threads means 10GB of memory. That's more than the average web server in the world.

All of these resources, is because you dedicated a thread for a user. BUT, most of this threads does nothing! they just wait for something to happen. and the OS has API for async IO that allows you to just queue an operation that will be done once the IO operation completed, without having dedicated thread waiting for it.

If you use async/await, you can write application that will easily use less threads, and each of the thread will be utilized much more - less "doing nothing" time.

async/await is not the only way of doing that. You could have done this before async/await was introduced. BUT, async/await allows you to write code that's very readable and very easy to write that does that, and look almost as it runs just on a single thread (not a lot of callbacks and delegates moving around like before).

By combining the easy syntax of async/await and some features of the OS like async I/O (by using IO completion port), you can write much more scalable code, without losing readability.

Another famous sample is WPF/WinForms. You have the UI thread, that all he does is to process events, and usually has nothing special to do. But, you can't block it or the GUI will hang and the user won't like it. By using async/await and splitting each "hard" work to short operations, you can achieve responsible UI and readable code. If you have to access the DB to execute a query, you'll start the async operation from the UI thread, and then you'll "await" it until it ends and you have results that you can process in the UI thread (because you need to show them to the user, for example). You could have done it before, but using async/await makes it much more readable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `absolutely not production` - Oh, if only that were true... :/

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new thread allocates a separate memory area exclusive for this thread holding its resources, mainly its call stack which in Windows takes up `1MB` of memory.

So if you have a 1000 idle threads you are **using up at least `1GB` of memory doing nothing.**

The state for async operations takes memory as well but it's just the actual size needed for that operation and the state machine generated by the compiler and it's kept on the heap.

Moreover, using many threads and blocking them has another cost (which IMO is bigger). When a thread is blocked it is taken out of the CPU and switched with another (i.e. context-switch). That means that your threads aren't using their time-slices optimally when they get blocked. **Higher rate of context switching means your machine does more overhead of context-switching and less actual work by the individual threads.**

Using async-await appropriately enables using all the given time-slice since the thread, instead of blocking, goes back to the thread pool and takes another task to execute while the asynchronous operation continues concurrently.

So, in conclusion, the resources async await frees up are CPU and memory, which **allows your server to handle more requests concurrently with the same amount of resources or the same amount of requests with less resources.**

Comment: Usually a server built around multi threading, and server built around async, Will use the same amount of threads.

Comment: @AK_ If there's actual asynchronous work to be done, then an async server will either use much less threads, or will use the same amount of threads but serve much more requests at the same time.

Comment: That's an incorrect understanding of multi threading. Work, and workers should be seperated. And usually threads(workers) should be picking up their work off one or more queues. Allocating more than, lets say, number of cores * 2-4 threasds does not make sense. Never.

Comment: And windows/ .Net provided asynchronous functions for IO decades before async....

Comment: @AK_ async-await isn't about multi-threading. It's about concurrency. The fact that windows has asynchronous I/O doesn't mean much for your application if you block a thread while using it.

Comment: You don't block a thread while using Overlapped, compleation ports, or BeginX/EndX . async/await is just a nice modern abstraction... And you don't end up implementing a state machine... But its neither free nor cheap...

Comment: @AK_ Begin/End is equivalent to using async-await in this regard. Most async APIs in .Net call Begin/End internally anyway. OP isn't comparing one kind of asynchronous implementation against another asynchronous implementation. The comparison is between async and sync.

Comment: @AK_: There's still a state machine for the `Begin`/`End` (or any other callback-based) approach. It's just that the state machine is explicit in the code, spread through multiple methods/lambdas, and is much more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to realize here is that a blocked thread is not usable to do any other work until it becomes unblocked. A thread that encounters an await is free to return to the threadpool and pick up other work until the value being awaited becomes available.

Comment: But isn't this handled at the OS level? When I run two console application with while (true) in there I can still operate my computer?

Comment: No, it isn't handled at the OS level. If you ran enough of them, your computer would run out of threads.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a synchronous I/O method, the thread executing your code is blocked waiting for the I/O to complete. To handle 1000 concurrent requests, you will need 1000 threads.

When you call an asynchronous I/O method, the thread is not blocked. It initializes the I/O operation and can work on something else. It can be the rest of your method (if you don't `await`), or it can be some other request if you `await` the I/O method. The thread pool doesn't need to create new threads for new requests, as all the threads can be used optimally and keep the CPUs busy.

Async I/O operations are actually implemented asynchronously at the [OS level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx).