# Is the IIS request processing thread pool the same as the TPL thread pool?

Tags: asp.net, iis, async-await, task-parallel-library

I know the Task Parallel Library(TPL) makes use of the Thread Pool to run tasks.
I've also read that IIS makes use of a "Thread Pool" to process incoming Http requests.
My question is: **Are these two referring to the same Thread Pool??**

Say I have this controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async void GetAsyncTest()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {//Do some heavy CPU work here});
}
```

Will the task be processed using a thread from the same thread pool as the request thread?

Comment: Recommended approach is not to start such work inside your app. Use dedicated service to do the long running job.

Comment: Sounds like I misled you. More details can be found in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee817661.aspx and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool They discuss further about the thread pool, which should be a single one.

Comment: The requests are handled using threads from the thread pool. `Task.Run` will do more harm than good because it will be exchanging one thread pool thread for another incurring in unnecessary thread switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**.

This is why it does not make sense starting a task for a **CPU-heavy** operation: it will use a thread from the same pool as other incoming requests so your application will **not be able to serve more requests as before**. And that beats the purpose of making things async in a web app: it is about **releasing threads** for other requests to use while an external **IO-heavy operation** (db request or http request to another service) is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Miklos. Is there any microsoft documentation that supports this? If so, would you share the link?

Comment: I couldn't find an official msdn article about this particular subject, there are only similar SO and forum threads (pun intended :) ), like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239722/why-use-async-controllers-when-iis-already-handles-the-request-concurrency or this one: https://forums.iis.net/t/1235033.aspx?Regarding+IIS+and+application+thread+pools+and+async